# Magento 2.4.3 on a Shared service

Tags: magento2, hosting, cpanel

I am wondering if there are any hosting providers out there that are not VPS that offer Magento 2.4.3+ and have Elasticsearch enabled. My current hosting provider offers Magento on it's cPanel, but I cannot "ping" the Elasticsearch service and I keep getting an "Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster"  error.
When I reached out to my hosting provider they said
"ElasticSearch in a shared environment is not ideal and we will not be supporting it on our shared servers."

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with share hosting but if you not needed the Elasticsearch for your project so remove from magento and install Mysql Legacy and it's working smoothly.

Remove elastic Search from Magento2.4.3+ follow below step.

First you can install from below the github URL and follow the installation step.

```
https://github.com/swissup/module-search-mysql-legacy
```

Also, you can install the following steps below.

```
composer require swissup/module-search-mysql-legacy

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/

php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'lmysql'


 Removed -  magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch
 Disabled - magento/module-elasticsearch
 Disabled - magento/module-elasticsearch-6
 Disabled - magento/module-elasticsearch-7
```

That it and It's working perfectly.